# ucontext.h and uc_link not returning from main thread

Tags: c

Here is what I want to do as part of a larger thread scheduling api.

I want to create a thread and when the main thread (the one creating the thread) exits, the thread I just created should execute. I am trying to do this with ucontext and the uc_link, but it is not working. It appears that my uc_link does not work when I try to set it for the current thread.

Here is a slightly modified example from this link which is what I tired to make this work.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/makecontext.html

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ucontext.h>


static ucontext_t ctx[3];


static void
f1 (void)
{
    puts("start f1");
    swapcontext(&ctx[1], &ctx[2]);
    puts("finish f1");
}


static void
f2 (void)
{
    puts("start f2");
    swapcontext(&ctx[2], &ctx[1]);
    puts("finish f2");
}


int
main (void)
{
    char st1[8192];
    char st2[8192];


    getcontext(&ctx[1]);
    ctx[1].uc_stack.ss_sp = st1;
    ctx[1].uc_stack.ss_size = sizeof st1;
    ctx[1].uc_link = 0;
    makecontext(&ctx[1], f1, 0);


    getcontext(&ctx[2]);
    ctx[2].uc_stack.ss_sp = st2;
    ctx[2].uc_stack.ss_size = sizeof st2;
    ctx[2].uc_link = &ctx[1];
    makecontext(&ctx[2], f2, 0);

    getcontext(&ctx[0]);
    ctx[0].uc_link = &ctx[2];
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output :

```
finished main
start f2
start f1
finish f2
finish f1
```

Given output :

```
finished main
```

How do I go about setting the uc_link for the current thread/process in a meaningful manner ?

Comment: This is what I'd expect in pthreads.  Once the main process exits, the threads would go away too.

Comment: There is a part at the end about the obsolete methods, is it useful in your case?

Comment: @pooya no, ucontext is a distinct technology and interesting in the context of co-routines -- my understanding is that ucontext is obsolete because it uses non posix approved pointer styles, which is not really a good reason not to use the library.

Comment: @bruceg - I understand that but if I wanted it to behave like pthreads i would use pthreads. :)

Comment: @gbtimmon But, the comment about the functions being obsolete and replaced with pthreads would seem to indicate that the behavior is the same.  There's no magic about threads.  The executable would normally go away when main returns.  And when the process exists, so do the threads. That's why you always see a pthread_join in the pthreads tutorials, so the main function waits for the threads to complete..

Answer (score 1):

Replacing main in the above code with the following produces the expected output.

```
int
main (void)
{
    char st1[8192];
    char st2[8192];

    getcontext(&ctx[1]);
    ctx[1].uc_stack.ss_sp = st1;
    ctx[1].uc_stack.ss_size = sizeof st1;
    ctx[1].uc_link = &ctx[0];
    makecontext(&ctx[1], f1, 0);

    getcontext(&ctx[2]);
    ctx[2].uc_stack.ss_sp = st2;
    ctx[2].uc_stack.ss_size = sizeof st2;
    ctx[2].uc_link = &ctx[1];
    makecontext(&ctx[2], f2, 0);

    getcontext(&ctx[0]);
    ctx[0].uc_mcontext.gregs[16] += 0x26;
    puts("finish main");
    setcontext(&ctx[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

**BUT** this doesn't do what you say you want.

The context functions are a way to put a specific return address on the stack.

- getcontext captures the address of the next instruction into a struct
- makecontext changes the address in the struct to that of its function argument
- setcontext/swapcontext puts the address in the struct on the stack and returns to it

This program above has only one thread of control.  I think you really want multiple threads, in which case you wouldn't use these context functions.

For more information about the stack and the C calling convention, Eli Bendersky has two nice articles with diagrams:

- [Where the top of the stack is on x86](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/04/where-the-top-of-the-stack-is-on-x86/)
- [Stack frame layout on x86-64](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/06/stack-frame-layout-on-x86-64/)

FWIW, to get the 0x26 constant in the above code, I had to disassemble main to find the first address after the setcontext call.

Answer (score 0):

At the link you provided they say

> The *uc_link* member is used to determine the context that shall be
>   resumed when the context being modified by *makecontext*() returns.

Since your program doesn't resume (execute) any context **modified by *makecontext*()**, the above does not apply and the program ends without resuming any context.

To achieve what you want, you have to define some function like

```
    void main_context()
    {
        // do everything you yet wanted to do in main()
        puts("finished main");
    }
```

and replace the

```
    return 0;
```

with

```
    char st0[8192];
    ctx[0].uc_stack.ss_sp = st0;
    ctx[0].uc_stack.ss_size = sizeof st0;
    makecontext(&ctx[0], main_context, 0);
    return -setcontext(&ctx[0]);
```